# Does having a nullable indexed column in the order by clause affect MySQL query performance?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance

I had a table with over a million rows and a select query that performed well until I had to do a schema change to make the column used in the order by clause to accept null values. That column has always been indexed. The only change was that it now allowed for null values.

After doing the change, the query performance degraded significantly causing 30x CPU spikes for the same traffic.

There is only once column in the order by clause. Something like `order by id desc` where id is an unsigned bigint and is indexed and defaults to `NULL`.

Dropping the index on this column solves the problem, but I have not been able to understand the underlying reason for this. I

Any idea what might have happened?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what storage engine does your table use? MyISAM, InnoDB, etc...

Comment: Are you aware if the index has actually been used in the query before/do you have the old execution plan? It might have been unused e.g. due to bad statistics (or other query restrictions), but after the change and a stats refresh, MySQL (incorrectly) assumed this index is good. (Especially if after removing the index, it's as fast as before allowing null). Or you changed your query slightly, not realizing that that's what slowed it down; or allowing `null` has some other indirect effect (e.g. a `left join` that was always a hidden `join` now really is a `left join` after you allowed `null`).

Comment: How do you confirm that it's because of nullable, not the query plan? Nullable column should be avoided if possible, but the performance gain is usually not that significant.

Comment: @dgig - Storage engine InnoDB

Comment: @Solarflare  - The assumtions are based on the change in performance. The query planner post the degraded performance started using the index on the colum that was made nullable. I did not look at the planner before this change so cannot precisely attribute to this change. Since this was the only thing that change, attributing the degraded performance to this change.

Comment: @Jacob Replied above

Comment: I don't doubt the effect (and that `null` caused it), but I don't think that ordering slows down significantly just because it *could* contain null now (if you didn't add lots of `null`s, which, like every data change, of course can have an impact). The best bet is that the execution plan changed (e.g. because the query *requires* it now, or for irreproducible things like refreshed stats), which we can't assess without query and/or execution plans; but if the execution speed after removing the index is exactly the same as before, it's likely that the index was unused before for some reason.

Comment: Give us something to work with -- the query, the schema, the percentage of `NULLs`, something!

Answer (score 0):

> Does having a nullable indexed column in the order by clause affect
>   MySQL query performance?

Yes it does.

> Declare columns to be NOT NULL if possible. It makes SQL operations
>   faster, by enabling better use of indexes and eliminating overhead for
>   testing whether each value is NULL. You also save some storage space,
>   one bit per column. If you really need NULL values in your tables, use
>   them. Just avoid the default setting that allows NULL values in every
>   column

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-size.html